# jsonp request returns 404 but the url is live

Tags: angularjs, rest, jsonp

I've been trying to hit this REST server, but ran into CORS issues. So I thought that if I did a jsonp request I could get the json data. Here is the request

```
  var url = "http://10.10.100.89:8080/locations";
  var trustedUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);

$http.jsonp(trustedUrl)
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }, function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });
```

and then the console shows a 404, but the url is live and when I navigate to the url with the browser I see the json
[image: when I navigate to the url this is what I see]

Any ideas why I'm seeing a 404?

Comment: What is trustedUrl variable equal to?

Comment: `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url)` which links to the url variable. This is basically saying that the url is trusted so we can access the page and we trust the url page

Comment: does the api support returning jsonp?

Comment: not sure but since I'm seeing json when I navigate there with the browser shouldn't it not have any issues grabbing that json from the url?